# How @scheduled annotation works in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot application in which I have a class with two methods likes below.

```
@Component
public class ClassA {
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 900000)
  public void methodA(){
    //do task "A"
  }

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 600000)
 public void methodB(){
    //do task "B"
 }

}
```

As per my understanding methodA should execute every 15 minutes and methodB should execute every 10 minutes. But as soon as applications starts both the jobs get invoked. Is this the right behavior ? If yes, then how can I stop them from execution immediately after application startup and run methodB after methodA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As form the documentation: [Scheduled (Spring Framework 5.0.4.RELEASE API)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html9)

> **fixedDelay**: Execute the annotated method with a fixed period in
>   milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of
>   the next.

What you want is

> **initialDelay**: 
>   Number of milliseconds to delay before the first
>   execution of a fixedRate() or fixedDelay() task.